# how to solve this function in O(N) time complexity instead of O(N^2)? or how can i improve time complexity?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have An array . I want pairs such that their sum is closest to 54. I know how to solve it. But solution that i know is taking O(N^2) time complexity. is there a way to get sum of all value pairs in O(N)  in javascript?

```
let arr = [20 , 30, 18, 40 , 22]
const x = 54

output (30,22)
```

Comment: _"is there a way to get sum of all value pairs in O(N) in javascript?"_ No, that's not possible. I'm not sure if this can be solved in O(N) but with binary search it can be solved in O(N log(N)). But I think you can use two iterators to solve this problem in O(N) with a sorted array. One iterator points to the first element and one iterator to the last element. Increment the first iterator If the sum is smaller and increment the second iterator if the sum is larger. But first you have to sort the array.

Comment: The number of pairs is O(n^2), so if you need to check all of them it wont work. However you don't necessarily need to do that. You could use a Set or some other data structure that allows O(1) or O(log n) time lookups. Loop over you array, say each element is `e`, compute `y = x - e` then check if `y` is in the set. If it is you have found a pair `e`, `y` that adds up to `x`. Alternatively sort the array and use binary search to check for membership

Comment: @GACy20 The first approach won't work because the question is about the closest sum, not the exact sum.

Comment: so first I should be sorting array. then use binary search which gives me 2O(N), which is same as O(N) . is that what you are saying?

Comment: @JaySardar neither sorting nor binary search are `O(n)`, they're like `O(n log(n))` at least.

Comment: @JaySardar also is there any additional context to this, just to check if we can add some "cuts" to the problem, like could it be that the original array will be already sorted?

Comment: no original array is not sorted

Comment: With a sorted array binary search approach has a time complexity of O(N log(N)) and the two iterators approach a time complexity of O(N). Since the array has to be sorted first, both approaches have a lower bound of O(N log(N)) because of the sort. I assume the two iterators approach will be faster. I can't think of a good approach without sort.

Comment: @ThomasSablik That depends on what OP really needs. To me it seems more like homework in an algorithms class, which is more about the complexity classes than actual execution time. If it really is about actual hard time limits, one has to do benchmarks with the actual data and environment anyways ...

Comment: @derpirscher To me it seems like a competitive coding website with hard time limits but you could be right.